# How to insert a huge amout of data to oracle database?

Tags: oracle, insert

First I query some data from user A and then I need to insert all this data to user B (user in oracle I mean) and I use Java to solve it. Below is my code:

```
while (ds.getResultSet().next()) {
    ResultSet resultSet = ds.getResultSet();
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("insert into ");
    sb.append(tableName.toUpperCase());
    sb.append("(");
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        sb.append(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        if (i != count) sb.append(",");
        else sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append(" values(");
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        Object colValue = resultSet.getObject(i);
        if (colValue == null) {
            sb.append("null");
        } else {
            if (colValue instanceof Date) {
                Date d = resultSet.getDate(i);
                String dateStr = DateUtils.formatDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                sb.append("to_date(");
                sb.append("'");
                sb.append(dateStr);
                sb.append("','yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss')");
            } else {
                sb.append("'");
                sb.append(resultSet.getObject(i));
                sb.append("'");
            }
        }
        if (i != count) sb.append(",");
        else sb.append(")");
    }
    conn = datasource.getConnection();
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
    ps.execute();
}
```

So it works a bit, but when it inserts above 80 records oracle just collaspses, and it's warning me in the console:[image: console window]

Can you guys give some advice to me about this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know about the error message, but unless you need to modify the data from Java, it's much better to move the data **inside** the database with `insert into target_table(c1, c2, c3) select c1,c2,c3 from source_table;`

Comment: A clean solution would be:1) create a procedure in package (DB), which accepts a custom type parameter as table type and inserts the data; 2) In java create a 2-dimension array, based on your created table type (google up the class "StructDescriptor") 3) Fill that array with values 4) call the procedure.

Comment: Close your result sets and prepared statements! That may solve the crash. But as others have said, there is no reason to do this in Java. If you really want to do it in Java, use bind variables and execute the same prepared statement over and over.

Comment: Looks like you are building a new `insert` statement from scratch for each individual record using literal values instead of binds, and getting Oracle to parse it and optimise it and cache it, and making a new database connection each time to execute it. I don't know Java but surely nobody would build and compile a Java method from scratch for each row in a huge dataset. Is there no way to code something reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guys suggest, I changed my code like below:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);         
PreparedStatement pspt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from SYS_DICT_TYPE");
ResultSet resultSet = pspt.executeQuery();                                    
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();                         
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();                                  
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();                                      
sql.append("insert into TEST_SYS (");                                         
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {                                      
    sql.append(metaData.getColumnName(i));                                    
    if (i != columnCount) sql.append(",");                                    
}                                                                             
sql.append(") values(");                                                      
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {                                      
    sql.append("?");                                                          
    if (i != columnCount) sql.append(",");                                    
}                                                                             
sql.append(")");                                                              
String s = sql.toString();                                                    

PreparedStatement pspt2 = conn.prepareStatement(s);                           
while (resultSet.next()) {                                                    
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {                                  
        pspt2.setObject(i, resultSet.getObject(i));                           
    }                                                                         
    pspt2.addBatch();                                                         
}                                                                             
pspt2.executeBatch();
```

The wired thing is: At the first I build the statement end with a ';' 
(the sql clause should like `insert into tablename values(?,?);`)
which cause  ora-00933:SQL error.When I removed the ';' it worked perfectly well.Why could this happend?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Java - just do it all in Oracle.

```
INSERT INTO b.table_name ( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM   a.table_name
  WHERE  some_column = some_value; -- Add filters if necessary
```

- You avoid having to dynamically build the query by parsing the meta-data.
- You avoid errors where you are not escaping single quotes.

  - Further to this, you avoid potential SQL Injection attacks where a user could enter something like the string `value', (SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE userid = 'Admin1' ) ) --`